# Jest failing to find nested test

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I have the following project setup:

```
.
|- package.json
|- library
  |- button
    |- button.test.tsx
```

When I run jest, it finds the test library/button/button.test.tsx, but gives the error message

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '<root-dir>/library/button.test.tsx'
```

when running the test.

As you can see it is not looking in /library/button, but just /library.

How do I solve this?

package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "\\.(ts|tsx)$": "./node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "testRegex": "./library/.*.test\\.(ts|tsx|js)$",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$":
      "./__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    }
  }
```

Comment: It looks like you want `testMatch[array]`, which supports file globbing. https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#testmatch-array-string

Answer (score 0):

Recommend setting the `roots` option:

```
{
  "roots": [
    "<rootDir>/library"
  ],
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$",
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "js",
    "jsx",
    "json",
    "node"
  ]
}
```

I personally use [src](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/testing/jest.html) folder only.